# MDDropdownMenu не работает в KivyMD

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

```
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.menu import MDDropdownMenu

KV = '''
MDScreen:

    MDRaisedButton:
        id: button
        text: "PRESS ME"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
        on_release: app.menu.open()
'''


class Test(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.screen = Builder.load_string(KV)
        self.menu = MDDropdownMenu(
            caller=self.screen.ids.button,
            items=[
                 {'viewclass':'MDItemMenu',
                  'text':'y',
                  'callback':self.call()}],
            width_mult=4,
            )
        #self.menu.bind(on_release=self.call())
    def call(self):
         print(1)

    def build(self):
        return self.screen


Test().run()
```

При нажатии на кнопку в выпадающем меню должна выполняться `self.call()`. При запуске кода функция сама вызывается 1 раз и не работает при нажатии на кнопку в меню. Я пробовал заменить `callback` на `on_release`, `on_press`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.menu import MDDropdownMenu
from kivy.lang import Builder

KV = '''
MDScreen:

MDRaisedButton:
    id: button
    text: "PRESS ME"
    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
    on_release: app.menu.open()
'''


class Test(MDApp):
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
    self.screen = Builder.load_string(KV)
    self.menu = MDDropdownMenu(
        caller=self.screen.ids.button,
        items=[
             {'viewclass': 'OneLineListItem',
              'text': 'y',
              'callback': self.call()}],
        width_mult=4,
        )
    #self.menu.bind(on_release=self.call())
def call(self):
     print(1)

def build(self):
    return self.screen


Test().run()
```

Нет такого класса MDItemMenu, если ты его только сам не создашь, дефолтные классы для MDDropdownMenu посмотри в документации kivymd https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components/menu/